# GeoServer returns "schema does not exists" when creating SQLView Layer using REST API

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I'm using GeoServer 2.16.2 (Kartoza/geoserver + postgis docker image) and I'm trying to create a SQLView layer using the REST interface. First I manually created the SQLView layer and copied the layer json description from the GeoServer REST interface. I then deleted the layer and tried to recreate it using a POST call to the GeoServer REST API. But this failed with the error **"Schema 'chuva_munic_semana' does not exist."**

The only 'complex' thing that I'm trying yo do in my SQLView is that my SQL statement contains a JOIN between two tables in PostGIS and uses a time dimension.

The funny thing is that doing a similar procedure but with a very simple SQL works. This makes me think that the problem lies with the SQL query.

Bellow is the JSON I'm sending to the REST API. `GEO_HOST` and `GEO_PORT` are parameters that are substituted prior to the `POST` call.

```
{
  "featureType": {
    "name": "chuva_munic_semana",
    "nativeName": "chuva_munic_semana",
    "namespace": {
      "name": "zarc",
      "href": "http://GEO_HOST:GEO_PORT/geoserver/rest/namespaces/zarc.json"
    },
    "title": "Chuva semanal",
    "abstract": "Chuva nos municipios",
    "keywords": {
      "string": [
        "features",
        "chuva_munic_semana"
      ]
    },
    "nativeCRS": "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\", \n  DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\", \n    SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]], \n    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]], \n  PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0.0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]], \n  UNIT[\"degree\", 0.017453292519943295], \n  AXIS[\"Geodetic longitude\", EAST], \n  AXIS[\"Geodetic latitude\", NORTH], \n  AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
    "srs": "EPSG:4326",
    "nativeBoundingBox": {
      "minx": -73.9831821599999,
      "maxx": -28.8477703530605,
      "miny": -33.7511779939999,
      "maxy": 5.26958083300002,
      "crs": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    "latLonBoundingBox": {
      "minx": -73.9831821599999,
      "maxx": -28.8477703530605,
      "miny": -33.7511779939999,
      "maxy": 5.26958083300002,
      "crs": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    "projectionPolicy": "FORCE_DECLARED",
    "enabled": true,
    "metadata": {
      "entry": [
        {
          "@key": "elevation",
          "dimensionInfo": {
            "enabled": false
          }
        },
        {
          "@key": "JDBC_VIRTUAL_TABLE",
          "virtualTable": {
            "name": "chuva_munic_semana",
            "sql": "select a.geocodigo as geocodigo, nome, ano, semana, data_ini, chuva, dias, wkb_geometry from dado_semana_munic as a left join lm_municipio_a as b on a.geocodigo = b.geocodigo\n",
            "escapeSql": false,
            "geometry": {
              "name": "wkb_geometry",
              "type": "Geometry",
              "srid": 4326
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "@key": "time",
          "dimensionInfo": {
            "enabled": true,
            "attribute": "data_ini",
            "presentation": "LIST",
            "units": "ISO8601",
            "defaultValue": {
              "strategy": "MAXIMUM"
            },
            "nearestMatchEnabled": true,
            "acceptableInterval": "P1W/P0D"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "store": {
      "@class": "dataStore",
      "name": "zarc:gis",
      "href": "http://GEO_HOST:GEO_PORT/geoserver/rest/workspaces/zarc/datastores/gis.json"
    },
    "serviceConfiguration": false,
    "maxFeatures": 0,
    "numDecimals": 0,
    "padWithZeros": false,
    "forcedDecimal": false,
    "overridingServiceSRS": false,
    "skipNumberMatched": false,
    "circularArcPresent": false,
    "attributes": {
      "attribute": [
        {
          "name": "geocodigo",
          "minOccurs": 1,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": false,
          "binding": "java.lang.String"
        },
        {
          "name": "nome",
          "minOccurs": 0,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": true,
          "binding": "java.lang.String"
        },
        {
          "name": "ano",
          "minOccurs": 1,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": false,
          "binding": "java.lang.Integer"
        },
        {
          "name": "semana",
          "minOccurs": 1,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": false,
          "binding": "java.lang.Integer"
        },
        {
          "name": "data_ini",
          "minOccurs": 0,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": true,
          "binding": "java.sql.Date"
        },
        {
          "name": "chuva",
          "minOccurs": 0,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": true,
          "binding": "java.lang.Integer"
        },
        {
          "name": "dias",
          "minOccurs": 0,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": true,
          "binding": "java.lang.Integer"
        },
        {
          "name": "wkb_geometry",
          "minOccurs": 0,
          "maxOccurs": 1,
          "nillable": true,
          "binding": "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Bellow is the (cliped) GeoServer log messages (logging level up to GEOTOOLS-DEV). I tryed to create the SQLView at 2020-06-10 13:50:33,211. 
The full log can be found at https://pastebin.com/y7NdLUur

```
2020-06-10 13:47:44,518 INFO [geoserver.logging] - Suppressing StdOut logging.  If you want to see GeoServer logs, be sure to look in '/opt/geoserver/data_dir/logs/geoserver.log'
2020-06-10 13:47:44,596 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 172.21.0.1
2020-06-10 13:47:44,597 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 3594ms
2020-06-10 13:48:01,669 INFO [rest.catalog] - Added workspace zarc
2020-06-10 13:48:01,670 INFO [rest.catalog] - POST workspace zarc
2020-06-10 13:48:05,956 INFO [rest.catalog] - POST data store gis
2020-06-10 13:48:08,900 WARN [geotools.xsd] - Sax parser property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' not recognized.  Xerces version is incompatible.
2020-06-10 13:48:09,564 INFO [rest.catalog] - POST Style chuva_semanal
2020-06-10 13:48:10,302 WARN [geotools.xsd] - Sax parser property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' not recognized.  Xerces version is incompatible.
2020-06-10 13:48:10,329 INFO [rest.catalog] - POST Style dias_sem_chuva_semanal
2020-06-10 13:48:53,633 WARN [catalog.impl] - Failed to load actual store for FeatureTypeInfoImpl[bc250_munic]
2020-06-10 13:48:54,762 INFO [rest.catalog] - POST feature typegis,bc250_munic
2020-06-10 13:48:54,799 WARN [catalog.impl] - Failed to load actual store for FeatureTypeInfoImpl[bc250_uf]
2020-06-10 13:48:54,878 INFO [rest.catalog] - POST feature typegis,bc250_uf
2020-06-10 13:49:12,356 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 172.21.0.1
2020-06-10 13:49:12,356 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 2000ms
2020-06-10 13:50:33,211 WARN [rest.catalog] - Unable to fill in metadata from underlying feature source
java.io.IOException: Schema 'chuva_munic_semana' does not exist.
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.ensureEntry(ContentDataStore.java:533)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:331)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:592)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:97)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.FeatureTypeController.featureTypePost(FeatureTypeController.java:246)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at 
<content clipped - too long>

org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.flow.controller.IpBlacklistFilter.doFilter(IpBlacklistFilter.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.flow.ControlFlowCallback.doFilter(ControlFlowCallback.java:260)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at 

< content clipped - too long >

java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-06-10 13:50:33,231 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: Schema 'chuva_munic_semana' does not exist.
2020-06-10 13:50:33,235 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Unable to flush 'http://zarc:chuva_munic_semana
java.io.IOException: Schema 'chuva_munic_semana' does not exist.
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.ensureEntry(ContentDataStore.java:533)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:331)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:303)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.flushState(ResourcePool.java:2679)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.flushDataStore(ResourcePool.java:2652)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:935)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:921)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.FeatureTypeInfoImpl.getFeatureType(FeatureTypeInfoImpl.java:123)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getDefaultStyle(CatalogBuilder.java:1567)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildLayer(CatalogBuilder.java:1516)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.FeatureTypeController.featureTypePost(FeatureTypeController.java:284)
    at 
< content clipped ...>

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-06-10 13:50:33,242 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - Schema 'chuva_munic_semana' does not exist.
java.io.IOException: Schema 'chuva_munic_semana' does not exist.
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.ensureEntry(ContentDataStore.java:533)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:331)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:303)

<content clipped -- was too long>

2020-06-10 13:50:33,244 WARN [annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] - Resolved [java.io.IOException: Schema 'chuva_munic_semana' does not exist.]
```

I also found this error coming from PostGIS docker, not sure if it's related

```
db_1         | 2020-06-10 13:48:53.664 UTC [348] docker@gis ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
db_1         | 2020-06-10 13:48:53.664 UTC [348] docker@gis STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM "public".GT_PK_METADATA WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: Please look in the GeoServer log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button. You may need to turn the logging level up to GEOTOOLS-DEV to see exactly what is going on

Comment: Thanks Ian. I added the log messages. Just noticed that I'm seeing `2020-06-10 13:48:53,633 WARN [catalog.impl] - Failed to load actual store for FeatureTypeInfoImpl[bc250_munic]` but those layers are created without any issues. And the SQLView layer that I'm trying to create uses one of those layers

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that the problem was how we choose to send the payload to GeoServer. We are using an R Script to open the JSON payload file (`jsonlite` package) and post it to the server (`httr` package). Our post call was:

```
res = POST(url = url, config = auth, body = fromJSON(payload), encode = "json")
```

Somehow, the `fromJSON(payload)` was OK for simple JSON files but, when we tried it whit a more complex payload (SQL View Layer), the content got messed up. A friend speculates that it could be related to boxing/unboxing ([]) of some parts of the file.

Anyway, we changed our `POST` line and now use

```
res = POST(url = url, config = auth, body = upload_file(payloadFile), encode = 'json')
```

And all works fine. So the trick was changing from `fromJSON()` to `upload_file()`